# ValueError in SKlearn from dimensions

Tags: python, pandas, scikit-learn

I have a DataFrame (as shown below) that is already set up with one-hot encoding. When I try to pass it into sklearn models, I keep getting dimension errors. If MultinomialNB only accept 1d arrays, how do I implement one-hot encoding?

| Color | Col B | Col C | Col D | Col E |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| red | 1 | 0 | 0 | 0 |
| green | 0 | 0 | 1 | 0 |
| blue | 0 | 1 | 0 | 0 |
| green | 0 | 0 | 1 | 0 |
| brown | 0 | 0 | 0 | 1 |

This runs fine:

```py
cv = CountVectorizer(max_features = 1500)
X = cv.fit_transform(df['Color']).toarray()
y = df.loc[:, df.columns != 'Color'].values

X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(X, y, test_size = 0.20, random_state = 0)
```

I get an error stating "ValueError: y should be a 1d array" when I run the following:

```py
classifier = MultinomialNB()
classifier.fit(X_train, y_train)
```

Comment: can you print the shape of y?

Comment: (50000, 12)


50,00 rows and 12 categories

Comment: As the error states, the y dimension should be (N,1)

Comment: How do I fix? :(

Comment: take only the column that is the label.

Comment: So Col B-E are the one-hot encoded labels. Col B is the first label, Col C is the second label, etc.